# Need help with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Is it possible to edit the query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1    
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN projects_status = 'active'  THEN 1
    WHEN projects_status = 'expired' THEN 2
    WHEN projects_status = 'closed'  THEN 3
    END
```

to have results in the following sorting order:

- Active projects_status ASC
- Expired projects_status DESC
- Closed projects_status DESC

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

A comparison will return a 0 or 1, where a 0 is normally sorted before a 1. So when you say ASC, you probably want it the return the rows where this is true (1) on top. So you need to use DESC in this case.

```
ORDER BY
projects_status = 'active' DESC,
projects_status = 'expired' ASC,
projects_status = 'closed' ASC
```